# How to extract List<int> from Dictionary<int, string>?

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I have a method that takes a `List<int>`, which is a list of IDs. The source of my data is a `Dictionary<int, string>` where the integers are what I want a list of. Is there a better way to get this than the following code?

```
var list = new List<int>();
foreach (var kvp in myDictionary)
{
    list.Add(pair.Key);
}

ExecuteMyMethod(list);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could do

```
var list = myDictionary.Keys.ToList();
```

Or

```
var list = myDictionary.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: the beauty is in the simplicity :-)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use the `Keys` collection in the constructor of the list:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>(myDictionary.Keys);
```

Comment: This solution is not only elegant, but also works on C# 2 and .NET 2.

Answer (score 1):

Like Guffa said that's some thing which is easy and elegant.
or

```
List<int> nList = myDictionary.Keys.ToList<int>();
```